# How to use reflection inside an attribute to retrieve information about the class that called it

Tags: c#, reflection, attributes

I got the following problem,

I got a class 'Car' with a function that uses EntityFramework to reach the Database and gets all the table rows by a few filters.

Something like this :

```
public class car
{
     private const string VEHICLE_TYPE = "something_here";
    [CachedAttribute(30)]
    public virtual List<Vehicles> GetVehiclesFromDB()
    {
        return _repository.Set<Vehicles>().Where(e => e.VehicleType == VEHICLE_TYPE && e.Weight < CAR_MAX_WEIGHT);
    }
}
```

I also added an attribute on top of it. Inside this attribute i need to be able to retrieve a few things,

I need to get the class name( in this case car),
I also need to get the type of the returned value of the function ( in this case the object Vehicles)
and i need to get the value inside VEHICLE_TYPE .

After that i need to be able to execute that function ('GetVehiclesFromDB') from inside the attribute

```
public class CachedAttribute : Attribute
{
    public CachedAttribute(int seconds)
    {

      // todo
    }
}
```

I never done those sort of things and i am not sure what is the approach i should take. Is it a case of reflection? or maybe it is something completely different?

Edit :

I indeed need to use this for cache, i want to use Redis for that.

Comment: That's not how regular attribute work. They are just metadata without any logic embedded. Some _external_ code inspects your code via reflection, sees different attributes and performs different actions based on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of attributes is to provide meta data or perform any request filtering such as Authentication/Authorization/Logging.

If you want to cache the output of the method then consider looking at the below ways

1. [OutputCache](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute(v=vs.118).aspx) attribute in case of an ASP.NET MVC Action method.
2. Use an utility class method that uses reflection ([Access Custom Attributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4a92379(v=vs.110).aspx)) to check the custom attributes of **GetVehiclesFromDB** method and cache the return value to the redis cache based on **CacheAttribute** arguments e.g. Time-to-live etc. This logic should be in the calling method of **GetVehiclesFromDB**.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Attribute class don't have to do anything, it's just data.

Class that call `GetVehiclesFromDB` have to check if `car` class have some attributes, and change logic with result.

To more help you can check this [article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/827091/Csharp-Attributes-in-minutes) in

"**Other than information what more can we do?**" section.

Answer (score 0):

Err.. that's not what attributes are for. They provide information about the element, but they can't interact with it.

From the name of the attribute you've declared, I would guess that what you want to do is something similar to this:

```
private List<Vehicles> _vehicles;
public List<Vehicles> Vehicles {
    get {
        if(_vehicles == null) {
            _vehicles = _repository.Set<Vehicles>().Where(e => e.VehicleType == VEHICLE_TYPE && e.Weight < CAR_MAX_WEIGHT);
        }
        return _vehicles;
    }
}
```

Obviously, I'm just guessing your intentions, so this might not be exactly what you intended, but hopefully should get you in the right track. For example, if you want to globally cache the list, you could use HttpContext.Current.Cache (if you are developing a web app) to store the values.